# How to clean Lightboard after recording marked with Neon markers

Tags: cleaning

Reaching out to this community as I believe maybe some of the users may using LightBoard for their video recording.

We are using Lightboard for our video production, results seem okey however cleaning is a mess. The provided image is the result after 15 minutes of cleaning efforts of one-time use.

Any help/pointers on the same are appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a comprehensive answer to your question:

https://revolutionlightboards.com/blogs/lightboard-resources/lightboard-cleaning-guide

Wipe off dry, then use foaming glass cleaner and a squeegee.

Answer (score 1):

Recommended cleaning is to only use glass cleaner, and this should work in a matter of seconds (assuming you have used the correct markers)

You will want a glass cleaner which contains both a solvent and a surfactant. Most big name ones do.